# client undefined in websocket server

Tags: node.js, websocket

when i print client in console log`console.log(`client ${client}`);` it shows undefined.
I think i should do something in my client code but don't know what.

**Server code -**

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, request, client) {
  console.log(`client ${client}`);
  ws.on('message', function message(msg) {
    console.log(`Received message ${msg}`);
  });
});
```

**client code-**

```
const Websocket = require('ws');
const ws = new Websocket('ws://localhost:8081');

function noop() {}

ws.on("message", function(event){
  console.log(event);
});


const ping = function() {
  ws.ping(noop);
}

setInterval(ping, 30000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ws` doesn't support `client` out of the box.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#client-authentication

the gist of it is that you need to use an HTTP server to listen to any connections (not using `ws` to listen) and "*manual*" emit the `connection` event with additional data (like client).

Comment: can you give me any example of authentication actually i am confused how can i send any key or something from client to authenticate.

Comment: I think I lost you. Can you elaborate on the `... from client to authenticate` part confused me.
What do you exactly mean when you say `client`? In the example `authenticate` is just an internal logic to extract an identifier from the `request` (like Based Authentication, JWT, etc.)

Comment: i want to know how can i put those identifier into the client request so that i can extract it in websocket server actually i am new in this

Comment: We are a bit off-topic regarding the original question. I highly suggest you research `JWT` and `Websocket Authentication`. There are many examples on the web and comment here are a challenge to convey it :). If you still find yourself struggling post another question  (post the link to the new question here. Then I will be able to follow)